# How can i restore a deleted team from Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I restore my deleted team in Microsoft Teams? It seems like there is no corresponding option for doing it?

With some reason, I deleted a certain team, As team didn't exist yet, so there is no something like "Manage team" option I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the team has been deleted, so there is no option to do it(Channel can be restored in "Manage team" option).

Cause a team in Microsoft Teams actully is a office 365 Group, So you can restore your it in Office365 Admin Portal, please ensure you have permission to do it. **Office 365 Admin Portal** -> **Exchange Admin Center**, navigate to *recipients* -> *groups*, here you can find the deleted team(group), select it and find the restore option at the top of panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore any deleted using AzureADPreview Powershell module. Learn this way is very important because this way you can make use of scripting and you can do bulk restore or perform multiple actions at once.

**Procedure**: Install AzureADPreview Powershell by running the following command and check your deleted Teams by running another command.

**Installation**: `Install-Module AzurePreview`

**Connecting**: `Connect-AzureAD`

**Finding Deleted Team**: `Get-AzureADMSDeletedGroup`

**Getting Object ID**: `$Objectid = (Get-AzureADMSDeletedGroup -All $True | where {$_.DisplayName -like "*Finance*"}).ObjectId`

**Restoring**:`Restore-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject -Id $ObjectId`

Complete Reference at: https://mcsaguru.com/how-to-restore-a-microsoft-office-365-deleted-team-using-powershell/